# How can I get HttpServletRequest from ServletContext?

Tags: java, servlets

Is it possible to get HttpServletRequest from the ServletContext?

Comment: Which `HttpServletRequest`?

Comment: Yes, this one. The request which corresponds with Http request of Tomacat.

Comment: What if there are 2 requests? What if there are 100?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Is it possible to have two requests at the same time?

Comment: Servlets would be a pretty poor tool for building web applications if you couldn't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> *Is it possible to get HttpServletRequest from the ServletContext?*

No.

The [`ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) represents the application. The application can cover many sessions and requests. But you can't get the "currently running" request or session via the `ServletContext`. Detail on how servlets and scopes work can be found in this related answer: [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-shared-variables-and-multithreading).

You're unfortunately not clear on the concrete functional requirement where you need this solution. You apparently have a `ServletContext` at hands somehow in an instance of the class of interest, but not a [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html). It's hard to propose an answer showing the right way how to grab the `HttpServletRequest` in an instance of such class anyway. Decent MVC frameworks like JSF and Spring MVC have ways to grab the `HttpServletRequest` associated with the current thread in any class you want.

In case you're not using a MVC framework and thus can't use its facilities, then you can achieve this manually by storing the request (and response) as a [`ThreadLocal<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) in the current thread via a servlet filter.

Here's a kickoff example how such a thread local context class can look like:

```
public final class YourContext implements AutoCloseable {

    private static ThreadLocal<YourContext> instance = new ThreadLocal<>();

    private HttpServletRequest request;
    private HttpServletResponse response;

    private YourContext(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        this.request = request;
        this.response = response;
    }

    public static YourContext create(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        YourContext context = new YourContext(request, response);
        instance.set(context);
        return context;
    }

    public static YourContext getCurrentInstance() {
        return instance.get();
    }

    @Override    
    public void close() {
        instance.remove();
    }

    // ... (add methods here which return/delegate the request/response).    
}
```

You can create (and close!!) it in a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) as below.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    try (YourContext context = YourContext.create(request, response)) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Do note that closing is very important. Otherwise the thread will get polluted after it has done its job and will be recycled for a different request or even a completely different purpose. In case you aren't on Java 7 yet and thus can't use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement as above, then use a `try-finally` block.

Then, in any artifact which is invoked by the same thread/request (i.e. other filters, any servlets, any beans/classes (in)directly invoked by those artifacts, etc), you can obtain the `HttpServletRequest` associated with the current thread as below:

```
YourContext context = YourContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpServletRequest request = context.getRequest();
// ...
```

Or, better create a delegate method, depending on whatever you'd like to do with the current request, such as obtaining the request locale:

```
YourContext context = YourContext.getCurrentInstance();
Locale requestLocale = context.getRequestLocale();
// ...
```

As a real world example, Java EE's MVC framework [JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) offers exactly this possibility via [`FacesContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html).

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Locale requestLocale = context.getExternalContext().getRequestLocale();
// ...
```

Comment: Actually I'm using Spring. And I invoke logic which needed a locale in the different thread. And this is the real problem. Thus, I can't use ThreadLocal.

Comment: Then just pass it as method argument.